# Serial new accounts to avoid question ban

Tags: discussion, support

Directly related to [What type of dialogue related questions are allowed here?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2736/what-type-of-dialogue-related-questions-are-allowed-here) inc answer & comments.

A good proportion of questions I'm seeing here every day for the past week or three are obviously from the same poster, asking one question after another about what is usually nothing more than English Language Comprehension.
They often appear in pairs, sometimes related, sometimes not.

They mostly get heavily down-voted & quickly vanish, along with that day's 'user'.

**This is intentional abuse of the system.**
Is there any way this can be curbed? Obviously it is circumventing the automatic measures put in place to prevent it.

This is a selection of recent ones [probably gone by next week]

[Why did Jack give an irrelevant reply to Tess's question?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71840/why-did-jack-give-an-irrelevant-reply-to-tesss-question)
[Why Evan says Tess lied to him about phonecall?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71842/why-evan-says-tess-lied-to-him-about-phonecall)
This one is obviously the same person, but different user name
[Why Matthew thanking peter for including Kenny Kristo name in Marie files?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71841/why-matthew-thanking-peter-for-including-kenny-kristo-name-in-marie-files)
This one at least appears to have some actual plot reference, but that still makes 4 questions in 4 hours, under 2 names.
[Why real DEA agents follow suspended DEA officer Matthew?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71837/why-real-dea-agents-follow-suspended-dea-officer-matthew)

This earlier one is also at least about some motivation rather than an element of 'lost in translation' but still gained a single downvote & no answers - user already shows as 'gone'
[What is significance of focusing on Kenyon Stone couples in whole movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71795/what-is-significance-of-focusing-on-kenyon-stone-couples-in-whole-movie)

This one actually got an upvote & answer
[Why does Abby think Owen not invite her in his house?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71749/why-does-abby-think-owen-not-invite-her-in-his-house)
Whilst that day's partner got nada - [How did Abby know Owen is in trouble at swimming pool?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71757/how-did-abby-know-owen-is-in-trouble-at-swimming-pool)

Scouring back a few days shows up more along the same lines, with the occasional one getting a vote or an answer, but there are many that I think are just gone, leaving no trace except a sour taste in the mouth.

Comment: The posts are gone because we delete the user and the system auto deletes their content.  I don't know the parameters by which the content is deleted, it may be downvoted questions with no answers only.  It's not the case for 'normal' user deletion - say when a user requests their account is removed.

Comment: This behavior has been seen and we've been attempting to manage it for a number of weeks.  The user(s) do not respond to comments or moderator messages.  Some IPs have been banned, but they keep coming back.

Comment: If anybody sees a post like this, flag it for moderator attention. Or post it in M&TV Moderation Room.